# Prevent AngularJs from outputting GET error messages to console?

Tags: angularjs

When I write `$http.get` request, even if I provide an `error` handling function:

```
function Ctrl1($scope, $http){
 $http.get('www.blahNonexistent.com/api').
 success(
     function(data){console.log("SUCCESS");}
 ).
 error(
     function(data){console.log("ERROR");}
 )
}
```

AngularJs still outputs the error to the console:

[image]

[Here is a minimal working example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W2AzM/).

Is there any way to prevent this behavior? (I don't want the use the think the site is broken, if one of the API endpoints is down)

Comment: @IanMercer Um.. that's because it actually exists :-) And returns 302 (success) status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a native error message and not an angularjs error, therefore I don't think you can "disable"/prevent it.

For example, if you add the following css to your fiddle, you will get the same GET error on the console:

```
div {
    background-image: url("image.png");
}
```

Comment: I realized this right after I posted my question haha. But it's nice to double check nonetheless. Cheers and thanks for all the fish!